# HDD not found in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I am installing Ubuntu for the first time. I have partitioned my hard drive into 40GB and 360 GB. After installing Ubuntu there's only 40GB. Where is the 360GB?

Comment: Your other 360GB probably is unallocated (AKA unformatted). You need to create a filesystem (eg ext4) in the unallocated space to use it.

Comment: You say you "have partitioned my hard drive into 40GB and 360 GB," but it's unclear what that means -- you might have a 40GB partition and 360GB of free space, a 40GB partition on which you've installed Ubuntu and a 360GB partition with no filesystem, a 40GB partition and a 360GB partition with a filesystem that's not mounted, or something else. Posting the output of `sudo parted -l` and `df -h` should clarify your current state. (Edit your question to add this information, and place four spaces at the start of each line of program output to preserve its formatting.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fdisk -l` to see your partitions.
If you wish to use partitions not allocated in setup, you have to allocate them and create a filesystem.(`mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdx#`)